# Calling docker commands from jenkins job as step running outside docker VM

Tags: jenkins, docker

I want to run a docker image create command from a Jenkins job which is running native on my machine with VM running Docker.

I've installed docker build step plugin and in manage Jenkins page command fails when I try to configure docker using url and version, it says:

> Test Connection Something went wrong, cannot connect to
>   http://192.168.99.100:2376, cause: null

I've got this docker url from the `docker-machine env` command.

In the version field, I tried both REST API version and Docker version, but no success.

Is it possible to call Docker from outside the docker VM and from a Jenkins job? If yes how to configure it in Jenkins?

Comment: 1) What OS are you running Jenkins? What OS is the Docker VM that you refer running? Is it Boot2Docker? 2) What docker version? 3) Why you need to use a docker step plugin? You could have a docker client in the Jenkins machine, connected to the docker daemon in the VM.

Comment: Jenkins running on win7 docker is on ubuntu from Docker toolbox docker $ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:20:08 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:20:08 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Comment: To my knowledge docker client dont work on windows hence i need to have VM to install linux so that i can install docker inside it , now jenkins is running on native Os while docker instance is inside VM on native OS hence i tried with Docker build step plugin  in jenkins

Comment: That is a new version of Docker that runs natively on Windows 10... You should install Docker Toolbox... It configires a specific lightweight VM for that called Boot2Docker